# Understanding Javafx runtime errors

Tags: java, javafx, runtime-error, illegalargumentexception

I wrote code for Sokoban game by using JavaFX but not completed one,
       here has three parts, first initialization, two more functions as you see.
       When I run the program, it makes a bunch of errors and it is the first time 
       for me to get such java errors, I think this is not a syntax error, please 
       give me your feedback if you know how to solve this, thanks.

```
public class Main extends Application {
    private double width = 32*20;
    private double height = 32*20;
    private int[][] grid;
    private int[][] targets;
    private Image image = new Image("man.png");
    private ImageView man = new ImageView(image);
    private ArrayList<ImageView> boxList = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
    private Pane warehouse;

    public void warehouseInitialize(){
        warehouse.getChildren().clear();

        int[][] tempGrid = {     {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}};
        this.grid = tempGrid;
        int [][] tempTargets = {{3,3},{18,18},{16,5}};
        this.targets = tempTargets;
        warehouse.setStyle("-fx-background-color:green");

        for(int row=0;row<20;row++){
            for(int col=0;col<20;col++){
                if(grid[row][col] == 1){
                    ImageView stone = new ImageView(new Image("stone.png"));
                    stone.setX(row*32);
                    stone.setY(col*32);
                    warehouse.getChildren().add(stone);
                }else if(grid[row][col] == 2){
                    ImageView box = new ImageView(new Image("box.png"));
                    box.setX(row*32);
                    box.setY(col*32);
                    warehouse.getChildren().add(box);
                    boxList.add(box);
                }
            }
        }

        man.setX(10*32);
        man.setY(10*32);
        warehouse.getChildren().add(man);

        for(int i=0;i<targets.length;i++){
            Circle circle = new Circle();
            circle.setRadius(16);
            circle.setCenterX(tempTargets[i][i] * 32);
            circle.setCenterY(tempTargets[i][i+1]*32);
            circle.setStyle("-fx-stroke:red; -fx-fill:blue;");
            warehouse.getChildren().add(circle);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)throws Exception{
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        Menu menu1 = new Menu("Tool");
        menuBar.getMenus().add(menu1);
        MenuItem menu12 = new MenuItem("Reset");
        menu1.getItems().add(menu12);
        menu12.setOnAction(e->{
            warehouseInitialize();
        });
        primaryStage.setTitle("Sokoban");
        primaryStage.setWidth(width);
        primaryStage.setHeight(height + menuBar.getHeight() + 64);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);

        VBox vBox = new VBox(menuBar,warehouse);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox,800,800);
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e->{
            switch(e.getCode()){
                /*case UP:
                    //goUp();
                    break;
                case DOWN:
                    //goDown();
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    //goRight();
                    break;*/
                case LEFT:
                    goLeft();
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
  public void goLeft(){
        int left1 = (int)((man.getX() - 32) / 32);
        int left2 = (int)((man.getX() - 64) / 32);
        int y = (int)(man.getY() / 32);
        if(grid[y][left1] == 0){
            man.setX(left1*32);
            man.setY(y*32);
        }else if(grid[y][left1] == 2 && grid[y][left2]==0){
            man.setX(left1*32);
            man.setY(y*32);
            for(ImageView box :boxList){
                int x_b = (int)(box.getX() / 32);
                int y_b = (int)(box.getY() / 32);
                if(x_b == y && y_b == left2 + 1){
                    box.setX(y*32);
                    box.setY(left2 * 32);
             }
         }
     }
  }
}
```

Here some errors when I run the program:

```
Exception in Application constructor
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)atsun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)atcom.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethod)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class sample.Main
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:907)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$160(LauncherImpl.java:819)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1118)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:620)
    at sample.Main.<init>(Main.java:24)
... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1110)
... 15 more
Exception running application sample.Main
```

Comment: The error is also posted

Comment: *Invalid URL: Invalid URL or 
resource not found* - it means it cannot find that image file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to wrong image path. To test you code you can use a web resource :

```
        Image image = new Image("https://candytech.in/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/man-1.png");
        ImageView man = new ImageView(image);
```

The posted code `private Image image = new Image("man.png");` should work when `man.png` is in the same folder as `Main`.
Not related to the question: `warehouse` is never initialized.

Answer (score 0):

The error is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
```

And the point in your code is here:

```
at sample.Main.<init>(Main.java:24)
```

Which if I am correct, refers to this line:

```
private Image image = new Image("man.png");
```

The problem is that `man.png` can not be found. However, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7830951/1270789) there are two possible workarounds. First, [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36253340/1270789):

```
private Image image = new Image("/sample/man.png");
```

By default, the root for `Image` is the `src` directory.

If that fails, [this might work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8088561/1270789):

```
private File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Yusuf\\Desktop\\Foundation of Multimedia\\lab\\Sokoban\\src\\sample\\man.png");
private Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
```

Here we create a `File` object that points to the required file then use `toURI()` to get a URI. You *might* be able to skip the `File` object by using:

```
private Image image = new Image("file://C/Users/Yusuf/Desktop/Foundation of Multimedia/lab/Sokoban/src/sample/man.png");
```

However, there might be issues with escaping space characters, etc, so it's probably easier to use the intermediate `File` object.

Comment: I changed to this ,              private Image image = new Image("C:\\Users\\Yusuf\\Desktop\\Foundation of Multimedia\\lab\\Sokoban\\src\\sample\\man.png");  but the error doesnot change at all

Comment: Please provide example of correct path for this case

Comment: @user8729892 OK, I've updated with a couple of possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace is quite detailed and gives enough information to debug. You could see a sequence of `caused by` which means the upper exception is caused by the exception below it.

So it's most likelt that your image can't be found at your specified location. Please recheck it and consider checking something about relative path.

Comment: could you suggest example for the correct form of the image path?